# B-mode and circular polarization in BICEP2

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics

In the case of the B-mode detected in BICEP2, at  first they  assumed there  was no circular polarization and then the  Q and  U stocks parameter of the CMB is given by  E-mode and B mode. If we have circular polarization too, what is relation between  the B-mode and circular polarization?  Does this B- mode include the contribution of circular polarization or Not not?